# Swift Group push notifications

Tags: swift, push-notification, notifications

i have social network app and... i want to know if there are possibility to group notifications on lock screen by this app.

My remote server send notification to APNs, then i receive it by device token. Is there any way to group notifications by app? I found code on medium, but i don't know how to implement it.

https://medium.com/swift-india/lets-take-quick-dive-in-grouped-notifications-5d41af9d6463

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    //over here add condition if same user has opened chat and notification is also from same user dont show these
    let extraPayLoad = (notification.request.content.userInfo["extraPayLoad"] as? [AnyHashable : Any])
    if extraPayLoad!["custom"] != nil {
        let info_string = extraPayLoad!["custom"] as? String

        let objectData: Data? = info_string?.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
        var json: [AnyHashable : Any]? = nil
        if let aData = objectData {
            json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: aData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [AnyHashable : Any]
        }
        if json?["sender_id"] != nil {
            if let aKey = json?["sender_id"] {
                print("sender_id : \(aKey)")
            }

            if(json?["code"] as? Int ?? 0 != 1003 && json?["code"] as? Int ?? 0 != 1004)
            {
                let unread_count_dict:[String: Bool] = ["unread_count":  true]
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showNotificationView"), object: nil, userInfo: unread_count_dict)
            }
            if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "_targetId") as? String ?? "0") == "\((json?["sender_id"] as? Int ?? -1))" {
                //
                // NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("GetAllConversationsList"), object: self)
                //return
            }
            if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "_groupId") as? String ?? "0") == "\((json?["group_id"] as? Int ?? -1))" {
                // NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("GetAllConversationsList"), object: self)
                //return
            }

        }
    }
    completionHandler([.sound, .alert, .badge])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if someone will need answer...

Just add **thread-id** field with any identifier to your server and push nots will group automatically by this id...)

[image]